# Angular.forEach returning only one result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

```
 $scope.$watch('selectedPoll', function(newValue, oldValue){
             if(newValue !== oldValue) {

               $scope.arrayResult.q1 = [];
               $scope.arrayResult.q2 = [];
               $scope.arrayResult.q3 = [];

               angular.forEach($scope.selectedPoll.questions, function(value, key) {
                   if (key) {
                        $scope.arrayResult = [];

                        var newArrayYes = [];
                        var newArrayNo = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i <    $scope.selectedPoll.survey_data.length; i++) {

                        if ($scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i][key] === "YES") {
                        var resultOfqYes = newArrayYes.push($scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i]);
                        }

                        if ($scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i][key] === "NO") {
                        var resultOfqNo = newArrayNo.push($scope.selectedPoll.survey_data[i]);
                        }
                        }

                        $scope.arrayResult.push({
                        value: resultOfqYes, color: "#46BFBD", highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                        label: "Yes"
                        });

                        $scope.arrayResult.push({
                        value: resultOfqNo, color: "#F7464A", highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                        label: "No"
                        });

                       $scope.arrayResult[key] = $scope.arrayResult;

                     return $scope.arrayResult[key];
                   }
               });
               }
           });
    });
```

I try to get three data sets arrayResult.q1 q2 and q3, one for each object in selectedPoll.questions but instead i get only third one, though when i putted console.log at the end of if statement, i saw that for each object of angular.forEach method there is individual console.log.

My question, If "if" statement is executed for each object (in my case three times) what i proofed by console.log, why then angular.forEach method return only one data for the last object in selectedPoll.questions ?

So where should i fix it to get three data sets, one for each object which is executed by angular.forEach method ?

Comment: Probably because you're setting $scope.arrayResult = []; at the beginning of each loop overwriting anything that was set on previous loops.

Comment: you were right i deleted $scope.arrayResult = [ ], i leaft it behind watch so i can extend it and added arrayResul[key].push and it work ;) thanks

Comment: np...I'll set it as the answer so you can close it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting $scope.arrayResult = []; at the beginning of each loop overwriting anything that was set on previous loops.